# display a dialogue box on click of a custom menu item in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt

I'm trying create a custom plugin, which adds an item (I will refer it as : **MyMenu**) to the *main menu bar* in eclipse. On click I should get a *dialogue box* which allows user to select some actions. I'm having a problem with how to create a dialogue box on clicking **MyMenu**. I have tried using ***WindowBuilder*** in eclipse, but it doesn't fulfill my requirement

Any help is highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

please see the always good Vogella's tutorials:
- http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseCommands/article.html
- http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDialogs/article.html#dialogs_jface

regards,

Comment: Already been through this tutorial, though it has helped me with various aspects on eclipse development, i did not find an answer for my current requirement

Comment: Please provide a more precise question.
What have you tried?
What is working? What is not working? Which error do you have?

Comment: I have made a main menu item (MyMenu), and added a command to it. On click of it I'm calling the command handler. But I'm getting this error ->
**Plug-in "MyRefactor" was unable to instantiate class "org.myrefactor.ui.MyRefactorHandler".**

Comment: The Code in the tutorial extends `Dialog` class, and I'm writing the handler which extends the `AbstractHandler` class